# Facebook Login is not working in android real device

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-fbsdk npm module for facebook login.
It is working in android studio emulator but not working in android real device.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Please check you facebook developer's application's setting. Also, make sure the enter the key hash generated.

Comment: @rohankangale Thanks for your reply.
Have checked developer setting and also generated key has.even thogh it is not working in real device but working in emulator

Comment: Please tell me what error you are getting.

Comment: hello @ShyamKumar, I'm having the same problem. Can you share what was the problem and how did you solved it?